# Regex to match three non-continuous digits where digits needs to be either 0 or 1

Tags: java, regex

```
For Eg:
 000=true
 111=true
 02010=true
 1011=true
 00101=true
 12001=false
 22200=false
```

```
   Pattern pattern=Patter.complie(".*0.*0.*0 || .*1.*1.*1");
   Matcher matcher=pattern.matches("00110");
```

This pattern is returning true either my string is "2";

Comment: Can you be more descriptive about the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such operator `||` in RegEx, only `|`, and it is good to wrap your options in parentheses. Also, the spaces in your expression are matched too. The right pattern is: `(.*0.*0.*0.*)|(.*1.*1.*1.*)`.
P.S. I suggest using [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) for trying out regular expressions.

Comment: Oh! Thanks for knowing me about the operator and parenthesis.

Comment: @Charul Thanks for marking my answer! Although, I would suggest using the Bohemian's solution, since it's more concise and flexible.

Answer (score 4):

I would just go with:

```
.*([01])(.*\1){2}.*
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/Auuu3T5pKWL4cd).

The uses a *back reference* `\1` to the character captured in group 1 for the repeat.

---

Add as many characters to the character class as you like, eg to include the characters `"2"`and `"3"` in the allowed list, use `[0123]`, or simply `[0-3]`

Comment: Thanks. Just a little confusion. What if I want the last case of Example to be true too, means same criteria that is applied to "0" or "1" applied to "2" also .

Comment: See edits to answer that allow more characters than just `1` and `0`.

Comment: Isn't `.*` at the beginning and end superfluous?

Comment: @cary In java (unlike most other language) string.matches() is only true if the *whole* string matches the regex.